# cakephp multiple pagination with same model but different condition

Tags: cakephp

I have a category and products table. In view, I need to list the data in the following way

**Category1 title** 
  id product name price (in a table) 
                Pagination numbers (I will pass the category id here)

**Category2 title** 
  id product name price
                Pagination numbers

etc
etc

How can I do the pagination for this ? On first pagination click, other paginations should not be changed. Categories are dynamic.

Comment: Im trying to do all things manually without using pagination methods. First Im looping through all categories and getting first page result for each category also Im taking the total count products of each category. And in view, Im looping through the data and creating ajax links. Is there any better way ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy direct cakephp way of doing this. But you can do it. You need is to customize the links so the pass on another variable identifying the parameter and then you have to parse it and do the pagination.

I google it and find the same solution but with a step by step tutorial :D

[How to have multiple paginators](http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-have-multiple-paginated-widgets-on-the-same-page-with-cakephp:48ad241e-b018-4532-a748-0ec74834cda3)

Here they use the model name to identify it but you will have to put something like model1, model2, etc so you identify which one is it, or simply numbers or words you need.